# Modal tabs in story board

Tags: ios, xcode, tabs, storyboard

Ive set up my new iOS app using storyboard with a tab controller with navigation views coming from it this works fine in storyboard as you can obviously create navigation controllers where you can provide the tab icon/text. What I want however is to have a couple of tabs which will launch modal actions (settings, add new record etc). If I try and connect a couple of views as model you don't get the tabs so I clearly missing something.  I've looked at maybe subclassing the navigation controller but apparently that is frowned upon.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If it's a modal view controller, it _should_ cover the tabs - otherwise the user can "dismiss" it by selecting another tab. Can you explain what you want more clearly? What should you see on the screen? What should the user tap to bring up the "modal actions"? What should they see at that point?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should have closed this as it's no longer needed.  Never got it working but redesigned the app to avoid the need.